# How to set CMRotationMatrix based on device position in OpenGL iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, accelerometer, core-motion

I am working on the app where i am developing an OpenGL object with coremotion functionality which will be rotating the object on device movement. And i am using the cmrotationmatrix of device motion to calculate rotation.
It works well on the device movement and also shows straight when the device is flat on the table.But if i change the angle of the device on start it shows bending.So is it possible to make the object to show straight at any angle of the device. Kindly response if anyone find solution.

```
  CMDeviceMotion *deviceMotion = self.motionManager.deviceMotion;
  float deviceOrientationRadians = 0.0f;
  deviceOrientationRadians = M_PI_2;
  GLKMatrix4 baseRotation = 
      GLKMatrix4MakeRotation(deviceOrientationRadians, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
  CMRotationMatrix a = deviceMotion.attitude.rotationMatrix;
  deviceMotionAttitudeMatrix
    = GLKMatrix4Make(a.m11, a.m21, a.m31, 0.0f,
                     a.m12, a.m22, a.m32, 0.0f,
                     a.m13, a.m23, a.m33, 0.0f,
                     0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f);

   deviceMotionAttitudeMatrix = 
      GLKMatrix4Multiply(baseRotation, deviceMotionAttitudeMatrix);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it shows bending"?

Comment: Actually the object sits on the side which means i can able to view the side view not the front view.if want to see the front either i have keep my device flat in the table or i have to touch and rotate.